# how to be aware of database changes without checking from android application

Tags: java, android

I'm Trying to Start an android chat room application , i can check server each 10Sec for new messages , but this is not right as you know.
For example when you receive an email , Automatically a Notification message Display
How Can I Do This ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is called Push Notification where you got notified from the server

the most common way to do this is using Google Cloud Messaging GCM

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

google it for some tutorials,

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you should absolutely stick with GCM because it makes all the applications use the same connection which is battery and user friendly.

Alternative is writing your own persistent tcp connection api or you can use MQTT. You can find a tutorial about it here [How to Implement Push Notifications for Android](http://tokudu.com/post/50024574938/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android)